# "We prefer questions which can be answered, not just discussed", discuss

Tags: discussion, feature-request, opinion-based

Stack Overflow questions which field opinion are routinely closed for attracting opinions.

In a largely fact-free world I absolutely value the call for factual responses, and for specific problems which can be finalised with specific working solutions.

However, not everybody who has a question wants this. Often, you want an opinion, and you want to know people's feelings because ultimately, they're relevant and they're relevant to decision making.

They're especially relevant when designing software you want people to enjoy using.

They're important when you're choosing software you want to enjoy using.

Yes, of course, opinion varies, but this does not invalidate opinion nor does it mean it contains no valuable information.

I would like to see Stack Exchange offer a better forum for opinion.

Especially when it is to ask for other programmer's experience of programmers' tools which may not have a purely objective answer.

As for this question, I don't necessarily want a factual answer, I actually want an opinion, I want people, who have feelings, to express them.

What's your view on asking questions which ask for an opinion?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the only site on the interwebs. If you want a "forum for opinion", find such a site.

Comment: This isn't what Stack Overflow is for, but there certainly are Stack Exchange sites that cater to questions leading to opiniononated answers, http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ springs to mind. This may be better asked on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: This has been tried: what is today Software Engineering Stack Exchange started as a place where all those more subjective discussions could be had. That didn't quite work out as planned though, it was quickly realized that without narrow guidelines you get quality problems.

Comment: Alternatively, [visit our evil twin](https://www.quora.com/Text-Editors-Which-is-better-Vim-or-Emacs-Why). They don't have any limits in this regard.

Comment: @hvd well, the thing with SoftRecs is that it doesn't ask for opinions, it ask for software that fulfills a very specific criteria. That's *not* asking for opinions.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @Braiam The answers there are not complete lists of all software that fulfil those criteria, they're the particular software that the poster thinks best fits.

Comment: @hvd if you notice, I'm objecting the notion that softrecs asks for "opinionated answers", since we don't ask which is "best" or "faster" but "which fits XYZ criteria".

Comment: @Braiam And I'm disagreeing with you. If multiple programs fit the criteria, I don't expect answers there to include all of them.

Answer (score 13):

Use Quora, done. Stack Overflow should only be used for technical question. For asking opinion, asking for experience, asking for stories, etc., use Quora. A lot of people misused one with another, so there you go, Quora and Stack Overflow in a nutshell .

Answer (score 7):

> when designing software you want people to enjoy using.

Then you need an UX expert.

> to ask for other programmer's experience of programmers' tools which may not have a purely objective answer.

Then you need to go and list your requirements, do a web search for tools that provide those requirements and compare the results to make a choice by yourself.

Other people's opinions are not relevant here. What one person might find a great tool, might be out of reach for another. Maybe it's too expensive, doesn't support the exact functionality they're looking for or is simply badly documented or supported.

Besides, when allowing such discussions, all it attracts are people who are coming to promote their product, without actually explaining how their tool does the job. It'll come down to an advertorial, like *"Our tool X can do that, see this link for purchasing details"*, while we expect answers on Stack Overflow to be stand-alone and definitive.

So no, if it's up to me, we're not going to share opinions on this site. Plenty of forums out there where you can do so.