# Clarification regarding "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed"

Tags: discussion

This seems like a very difficult-to-define requirement. I understand that Stack Overflow is a place for asking technical questions, not a forum for discussing opinions or ideas.

And I have referenced the discussion here about this same topic - ["We prefer questions which can be answered, not just discussed", discuss](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338521/we-prefer-questions-which-can-be-answered-not-just-discussed-discuss)

But what about technical questions that don't yet have an existing or commonly-accepted solution? Is it appropriate to ask a technical question on stack overflow about a novel, unsolved problem? Its entirely possible that such questions couldn't be answered, only discussed. Yet, those questions would still be technical and not a matter of opinion or abstract ideation.

Comment: Guess you found out that not all coding questions have a home on Stack Overflow.

Comment: _"But what about technical questions that don't yet have an existing or commonly-accepted solution?"_ Is fairly ambiguous. Plenty of questions asked on Stack Overflow had not been asked and answered before being asked here. If it is a practical, answerable programming problem (not all programming _questions_ are on-topic, we're here for solutions to programming _problems_ (with some exceptions)), then there shouldn't be an issue. If you're not asking for a solution to a programming problem, but rather a discussion about a topic, then it won't be on-topic here.

Comment: Hmm... let me try to clarify. I mean asking a specific question, about a specific well-defined problem, but which doesn't yet have a commonly-accepted or documented solution. That might inevitably *lead* to discussion, if answers can't be found, but its not an abstract prompt.  I guess its the difference between , "I know this is possible, but why isn't this working?"  as opposed to  "Here's what I'm trying to do exactly, is this possible? If so, have you found a solution?"

Comment: If it is a specific well-defined programming problem with a clear and concise practical, answerable programming question, then it is likely to be on-topic (specific examples may or may not be on-topic for other reasons). The fact that a practical, answerable programming problem may attract some amount of discussion is sometimes unavoidable. The point is that we're not here for "Discuss <thing>", we're here for "How to do <thing>"/"How to fix <thing>"/etc.

Comment: I definitely get your final point. I guess what I'm wondering is, how do you know if a novel question is answerable, assuming an answer hasn't yet been documented? This might be venturing into the philosophical realm though..... :-P

Comment: Keep in mind that "is this possible?" is a fairly useless question as all answers would either be "Yes" or "No". If the answer is "yes" you would, undoubtedly be wanting to know how it can be done. If the answer is "no", you would undoubtedly be wondering why it isn't possible. Just ask how to accomplish the task, then an answer such as "This is not possible because <x>" would still be appropriate.

Comment: Well yes, that question by itself is certainly useless.

Comment: Re: "how do you know if a novel question is answerable": If you can see the question receiving an _answer_ (i.e. "Just do X, Y, Z" or "This is not possible because <x>") then it is answerable. If the only _answers_ it could receive would be an opinion statement, then it isn't answerable. It's more about the phrasing of the question than the likelihood of there being a viable solution that matters.

Comment: *doesn't yet have a commonly-accepted or documented solution* The solution doesn't have to be commonly accepted or documented to be valid, it just has to work. It's entirely possible that some of the unanswered questions here are unanswered because no one could find a solution or prove that a task isn't possible but that doesn't make the question itself off-topic.

Comment: For example: "How can I access the parent document of a sandboxed iframe?" is a valid on-topic question even though the answer is "This is not possible (unless the 'allow-same-origin' flag is set) because the sandbox flag disallows such behavior".

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answers folks. It seems what Stack Overflow accepts in theory is different than what it accepts in practice, however . ;-)

Comment: also somewhat related: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Comment: I saw both of those but I don't think they are duplicates. In my prompt, I'm talking about asking a question that seeks a specific solution about a specific problem. Those questions deal specifically with *wanting* discussions or brainstorming. I'm talking about wanting a technical solution that might not exist, therefore the question might not be technically 'answerable' - unless you count 'not possible' as an answer, as commenters described above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what about technical questions that don't yet have an existing or commonly-accepted solution? Is it appropriate to ask a technical question on stack overflow about a novel, unsolved problem?

Yes. If it is a practical, answerable question about programming, then it is on topic here.

We do not require that an answer exists—only that an answer *could* exist. Many successful questions here have been the inspiration for extensive research, and, as a result, have produced fantastic answers, some of them even breaking new ground and establishing new patterns/practices.

> Its entirely possible that such questions couldn't be answered, only discussed.

For questions where that is the case, they are off-topic here.

Now, you have to be a bit careful, because *anything* can be discussed. You can take a perfectly on-topic, answerable programming question and turn it into an endless sea of discussion. That doesn't make the question bad; it just makes the answers bad.

What we are trying to prevent are open-ended, bikeshedding questions where no definitive answer can *possibly* exist. This is expanded upon in the Help Center's page on the [types of questions you should avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

> “We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed” ... seems like a very difficult-to-define requirement.

It doesn't seem difficult to me at all, and I'm struggling to understand your confusion. We don't want discussion: we want answers. That's the whole point of Q&A, and it is the primary feature that sets us apart from other sites that are more geared towards discussion.

> It seems what Stack Overflow accepts in theory is different than what it accepts in practice, however.

Only because Stack Overflow is not a perfect model of its guidelines. We get a *lot* of questions, and we simply cannot get around to identifying and closing all of the questions that fall outside of our scope. The result is that you certainly will find off-topic questions being asked and even answered here. That doesn't change the fact, though, that such questions are off-topic and subject to being closed at any moment, nor does it change the fact that the guidelines exist and we expect you to avoid asking questions that run afoul of them.

You especially see this with very old questions, asked before the current guidelines were established. The current guidelines were largely informed by experience we gained from trying to ask and answer these old questions and finding out that they just didn't work all that well.

Comment: My confusion is mainly that I had a question downvoted nearly-immediately, and I've seen similar questions downvoted that fit the description I provided above. So I was curious if this was a place to find potential or theoretical solutions, or a place for getting help with known / documented answers. 

And you're right its not difficult-to-define after seeing the explanations here. I was saying it was difficult-to-define because I was thinking of it more literally, as in, this question has an answer and someone can provide it. Not- this question is theoretically answerable.

Comment: And to me, if I haven't found an answer out there, and I haven't been able to get any of my ideas to work, I have no clue if the question is 'answerable' -  but I was being too literal.

Comment: You had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898527/static-hosting-of-angular-app-possible-for-a-file-in-one-location-to-bootstrap) downvoted. Not closed. Not even any comments that it was off-topic. Being off-topic is not the only reason for a question to be downvoted.

Comment: Ok, I'm very new here and I'm genuinely trying to understand why the community seemed reluctant to field that question and other ones that I feel are great questions but are mostly ignored. I'm not trying to play victim

Comment: You asked the question 11 hours ago on a weekend. I don't really think it's fair to conclude that the community is "reluctant to field that question". (Also, sorry, I had to delete the answer you got to that question because it was plagiarized from another source without attribution. Maybe the author of it will fix that and enable it to be undeleted.)

Comment: Probably true, but it was downvoted to -4 within less than a minute, so it seemed like a message was being sent, lol

Comment: Oh, whoops. Is hyperlinking to the source not enough? Or are you saying it was plagiarized on the site that hosted the question

Comment: He didn't link to the source. He linked to his blog, which *also* contained plagiarized material. What appears to be the original source was never mentioned anywhere in the answer. We have [clear guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) for how to reference material from external sites; I left him a link to that. (You can't see other people's deleted answers, but they can see their own.) And that question you asked was only downvoted to -2, not -4.

Comment: I see. Yes it came back up eventually. But it was at -4 nearly immediately after posting. Which is why I was confused.

Comment: Just like this question :-)

Comment: Yeah, but voting on Meta is very different. It usually signifies agreement/disagreement with the premise of a post, and it doesn't affect your reputation in any way.