# Is it OK to ask a question about RDF/XML that is not a programming question?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I'm trying to see if a Linux tool exists that validates RDF/XML and can deal with what appears to not be a normal situation. Or, perhaps I'm not understanding how to properly use the tools I've encountered. This is not a programming question, so my gut feeling tells me not to post it here, but I see some broad semantic web questions on Stack Overflow:

- [What is the semantic web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725261/what-is-the-semantic-web), closed for not being focused enough but got 10 answers.
- [What is the difference between Semantic-markup and Semantic Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579802/what-is-the-difference-between-semantic-markup-and-semantic-web), broad and not closed.
- [What is the difference between RDF and OWL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740341/what-is-the-difference-between-rdf-and-owl), broad and not closed.

Is it OK to post my question here?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem anything like those other examples.  Yours is a recommendation question.  Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: **so my gut feeling tells me not to post it here** Follow that gut feeling. It won't steer you wrong.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My question is part recommendation and part trying to understand how these XML parsers work. It's a focused question. My concern with posting to softwarerecs is that there are only 38 posts with "rdf" in them.

Comment: "How [something] works" is too broad.  Is your actual question more specific than that?

Comment: Topicality matters.  Asking a question somewhere because the audience is bigger, but you know it's off-topic, isn't going to work well.  It just means you'll get a bad reception.

Comment: Perhaps it's a different question but I'm wondering why broad questions like the ones I referenced are allowed on stackoverflow. They don't seem to me to meet the guidelines for posting questions here.

Comment: It sort of sounds like yu have 2 questions: 1) recommendations, 2) How XML Parsers work. In that case, I would follow Robert Harvey's advice about softwarerecs for 1, and research 2 to the best of your ability. If you still have unanswered questions about 2 after that, then come back to SO and ask it.

Comment: *"broad questions like the ones I referenced"* You do understand that these were asked over 9 _years_ ago? The rules on Stack Overflow were much different back then.

Comment: Thanks, everybody, for your input. I won't be posting the question here, at least not in its current form.

Comment: Those links are all too-broad & no research. Close & downvote. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. (But they are old.) "Difference between" is just a way for people to sound like they bothered to find out what the things were & compare them when really they don't know what both are--if they did they could/would present a difference & ask for feedback. Don't ask for yet another presentation of something, ask 1 specific question re the 1st place you are stuck in a presentation that you reference & quote.

Comment: ["Stack Overflow is not a perfect model of its guidelines. We get a *lot* of questions, and we simply cannot get around to identifying and closing all of the questions that fall outside of our scope. The result is that you certainly will find off-topic questions being asked and even answered here. That doesn't change the fact, though, that such questions are off-topic and subject to being closed at any moment \[. . . \] You especially see this with very old questions, asked before the current guidelines were established."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355737)